# Induction to show that $\sigma_1\circ\ldots \circ\sigma_k(q_i)=p_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p\neq q\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $v:=q-p$ and $m:=\frac{1}{2}(p+q)$.

Let $H_{p,q}:=\left \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid d(p,x)=d(q,x)\right \}$.

I have shown that $H_{p,q}=m+v^{\perp }$.

Let $\sigma_{pq}=\tau_m\circ\sigma_v\circ\tau_{-m}$. It holds that $\sigma_{pq}$ swaps the element $p$ and $q$.It also holds that $\sigma_{pq}$ fixes all points in $H_{p,q}$.

Let $\Sigma=\{\sigma_{p,q}\mid p\neq q\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}=\{\text{id} \}\cup \Sigma$.

Let $1\leq k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p_1, \ldots , p_k, q_1,\ldots ,q_k\in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $d(p_i,p_j)=d(q_i,q_j)$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq k$. Then there are $\sigma_1,\ldots , \sigma_k\in \hat{\Sigma}$ such that for all $1\leq i\leq k$ it holds that $\sigma_1\circ\ldots \circ\sigma_k(q_i)=p_i$.

Using induction on $k$ I have done the following :

Base Case : For $k=1$ we have that $\sigma_1(q_1)=p_1$.
It holds that $\sigma_1\in \hat{\Sigma}$, since $\sigma_1$ swaps $p_1$ and $q_1$ we get $\sigma_1(q_1)=p_1$.

So the statement is true for $k=1$.

Inductive Hypothesis : We assume that the statement is true for $k=n$, i.e. $\sigma_1\circ\ldots \circ\sigma_n(q_i)=p_i$, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Inductive Step: We want to show that for $k=n+1$ it holds that $\sigma_1\circ\ldots \circ\sigma_n\circ \sigma_{n+1}(q_i)=p_i$, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n+1$.

It holds  that $\sigma_{n+1}\in \hat{\Sigma}$, so the map swaps $p_i$ and $q_i$, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n+1$.
So it holds  that $\sigma_{n+1}(q_i)=p_i$, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n+1$.

But how can we use the inductive hypothesis?